# Bitmap Compress Getting null after taking picture and save into server

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Im trying to save my picture after taking photos from default camera and store it into server.

But after i succeed set the bitmap into the imageview, and then i press the button to store the photo into server, the error is occured :

***Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference***

This is my code overall :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

    cmdSelesai.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bao);  <--- This line is error
            byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
            ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.NO_WRAP);
            new uploadToServer().execute();
        }
    });
```

**OnActivityResult :**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1888 && data != null)
        {
            selectedImage = data.getData();
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
        else if (data == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Batal mengambil gambar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bp);
        }
    }
```

**OnSaveInstance and OnRestoreInstance :**

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putString("order", order);
        savedInstanceState.putString("shipment", shipment);
        savedInstanceState.putString("penerima", penerima);
        savedInstanceState.putString("kode_driver", kode_driver);
        savedInstanceState.putString("picturePath", picturePath);
        savedInstanceState.putStringArray("kode_produk", kode_prdct_temp);
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable("selectedImage", selectedImage);
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable("bm", photo);
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable("photo", photo);
        savedInstanceState.putSerializable("myMap2", (Serializable) myMap2);
        savedInstanceState.putSerializable("mapAlasanReal", (Serializable) mapAlasanReal);
        // etc.
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        order = savedInstanceState.getString("order");
        kode_driver = savedInstanceState.getString("koder_driver");
        shipment = savedInstanceState.getString("shipment");
        penerima = savedInstanceState.getString("penerima");
        picturePath = savedInstanceState.getString("picturePath");
        bm = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bm");
        photo = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("photo");
        kode_prdct_temp = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("kode_produk");
        selectedImage = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("selectedImage");
        myMap2 = (Map<Integer, Integer>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("myMap2");
        mapAlasanReal = (Map<Integer, Integer>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mapAlasanReal");
    }
```

Please help me !

**EDITED :**

This is my permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: `bm` is `null`. Now you should research why `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` is returning `null`. You are welcome.

Comment: `decodeFile` is returning null. Are you sure that the path is correct and you have the permissions to read it ?]

Comment: Always wrap lines of code that can produce NPE or any other Exception inside try...catch. Like `bm.compress...`